# Android Tab that holds other Tabs

Tags: android, tabs

Basically, right now I have an Android app that has four tabs on the top. One of the tabs is 'Settings', but instead of it being on of four tabs I have, I want it to be inside another tab called 'Demos,' so when someone clicks the 'Demos' tab, they can click a button to open the 'Settings' page and in the future any other activity tabs I want. A screenshot is below of what the iOS equivalent is if what I wrote is confusing. Thanks. [image]

Comment: So you basically want to create a button within the Demos fragment that opens an Activity correct?

Comment: Yeah...sounds a lot better when you say it I just started learning Android so I did not know how to say it correctly

Comment: No problem. I was just trying to make sure I understood what you were trying to do. When creating your demos layout xml, add a settings button. Then in your fragment code, add an `onClickListener` to your button to take you to the new activity.